# Vim: Recommendations for vimball plugins in pathogen

Tags: vim

I plan to switch to vim 7.3 in the next days on my windows box - linux will soon follow. I also plan to switch my vim setup and let pathogen handle my plugins.
I've googled but not yet found a solution how to handle plugins using vimball technique for setup. Any hints?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You are looking for `:UseVimball [path]`

Open the vimball up with vim. Instead of sourcing it with `:so %` do

```
$ vim somthing.vba
:!mkdir ~/.vim/bundle/bundle-dir-name-here
:UseVimball ~/.vim/bundle/bundle-dir-name-here
```

Note you will have to make sure the path exists before you execute this command.

```
:h :UseVimball
```

Comment: Just an FYI: if you have a trailing space after your `dirname`, you'll get an error message about only 1 file name allowed. Also, you don't need to wrap the path in quotes; apparently, pathogen does that for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just converted a VimBall to a pathogen bundle [here](https://github.com/hrj/vim-DrawIt)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [vim-addon-manager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2905): it is able to put every plugin in a separate directory and correctly handles Vimball.

Comment: Irrelevant answer since he is referring to a particular plugin manager "Pathogen"

Comment: Ok, what is it then?
What do you consider a plugin manager to be?

Comment: @bergercookie It is a path manager. Plugin manager *manages* plugins, pathogen *only* tells Vim to load plugins. “Managing” here means at least ability to install and remove plugins, additionally it may update, handle dependencies, tell Vim how to load them (though without the last thing manager is very inconvenient to use, so all plugin managers know how to tell Vim to load plugins they installed, as well as other similar software (portage, apt-get, etc; pip, cargo, etc): but with the existence of pathogen one may design a plugin manager which relies on pathogen to load plugins).

Comment: @bergercookie Also open pathogen README and find a word there which says it is a plugin manager. There are no, author never positioned it like this: README directly says “Manage your 'runtimepath' with ease”: “runtimepath”, not “plugins”.